# Bind clicked-event to empty space/area in a div with jQuery

Tags: jquery

*I want to have a click-event in jQuery that tells when clicked on an empty area/no content-area:*

I have some divs with classes:

```
<div id="products-area">
<div class="products">
    <div class="product">
        <div class="image-wrapper"></div>
        <div class="handles"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="product">
        <div class="image-wrapper"></div>
        <div class="handles"></div>
    </div>
      ¨
    <!-- I want to have a function to tell when clicks on "empty area". like here -->    
</div>
</div>
```

I've tried with this:

```
$("#products-area").on('click', '.products .product', function(){
    //Do something when clicked on a product
});   

$("#products-area").on('click', '.products', function(){
    if (!$(this).hasClass()) { //This obviously doesn't work
        //Do something when the object click on is not a product or some div inside of the product-div
        //but it has to be inside of #products-area
    }            
});
```

This is what I want:

When user clicks somewhere in products-area and it is NOT a product (and is NOT some of the divs inside of the product-div), then do something.

**How do I achieve that?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

check if events target is same to the clicked element..
try this

```
$("#products-area").on('click', '.products', function(e){
   if(e.target == this){
     //do something...
   }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Inspect the event `target` and see if it is a `.product` or a child of `.product` using `.closest`:

```
$("#products-area").on('click', function(e){
    if($(e.target).closest('.product').length > 0) return;
    alert('no product clicked!');
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/aCmJn/)

Comment: Thanks! Would this be a better solution than bipens? Why / why not?

Comment: Bipens answer is tidy; go with it if it suits you. My code listens to all clicks anywhere in `#products-area` and explicitly discards the ones that were on a product or a child of a product. Bipens code listens to all clicks in `.products` and discards those that were on any child element. From the scenario you've shown, both will work, but if you add some other element to `.products` that isn't a product, my code will show the `no product clicked` alert, but bipens code will not handle that as a *no product* click.

Comment: Of course, both may end up being the desired behavior, seeing as we can't know what this hypothetical future element would be. Whichever code you end up using, just make sure you know what it does, so that you can anticipate when your changes will break it.

Comment: THANKS for the explaination! Very good! If I could I would upvote your answer even more :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$("#products-area").on('click', function(e){
    var $target = $(e.target);

    if(!$target.closest('.product').length){
        console.log('s')
    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ANxNf/)